# What is meant by Intertestamental Literature?

Tags: old-testament, apocrypha, deuterocanonical-books

We read in Jude 1:14-15:

> Enoch, who lived in the seventh generation after Adam, prophesied about these people. He said, “Listen! The Lord is coming with countless thousands of his holy ones  to execute judgment on the people of the world. He will convict every person of all the ungodly things they have done and for all the insults that ungodly sinners have spoken against him.”

Footnote under the verses reads:The quotation comes from intertestamental literature: Enoch 1:9.

My question is: What is meant by Intertestamental Literature ?

Comment: +1 ... I can't understand why anyone would downvote this question. There's nothing wrong or controversial about it that I can see. Is it because they thought you should look it up yourself?

Comment: Thanks, Dan Fefferman, for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intertestamental literature, as the name implies, is Jewish religious literature (as opposed to philosophy and history) written between the two "testaments." It covers the period between the last books of the Hebrew Bible and the earliest New Testament writings: the letters of Paul.

The issue is complicated by the question of the authorship of the Book of Daniel, which is traditionally dated to the Babylonian exile but is thought by many contemporary scholars to have been produced during the Maccabean Revolt during the second century b.c.e. If so, it too would be "intertestamental" but is not counted as such due to its being included in the OT canon.

The Apocrypha are also intertestamental literature. Jews and Protestants do not consider them to be holy scripture, but Catholics and the Orthodox do. Finally, there are a number of later frauds once considered to be intertestamental but now categorized as pseudepigrapha of a later time.
Various otherwise unknown scriptures found among the Dead Sea Scrolls are not normally counted in the category of intertestamental literature due to their recent discovery, although a case could indeed be made for them.

[This link](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/the-apocrypha-and-pseudepigrapha) leads to an article with a list of intertestamental works.

Comment: The statement about the Apocrypha and Protestants isn't quite accurate:  there were and are Lutherans who consider them canonical; it's worth noting that Luther translated these books and they were included in every "Luther Bible" right into the early nineteenth century.  They were just regarded as Deuterocanonical, "second canon", which meant they were on a lower level and thus not to be used to found any doctrine on but only to support doctrine established by the primary canon (a rule that was also applied to the NT books that were "antilegomena", i.e. "spoken against").